# Should I use make or makes after 'that'

Tags: verbs, that

> To set global allowance we need to type one or two values that **make(s)**
>   up the allowance

Comment: I would side-step the issue by writing "To set **the** global allowance we need to type one or two values which will make up that allowance."

Answer (score 3):

When a compound subject contains – or, in this case, implies – both a singular and a plural noun or pronoun joined by "or" or "nor," the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is nearer to the verb.  Since "two values" is nearer to the verb and plural, you would use the plural conjugation "make," not the singular conjugation "makes," which would correspond to the singular "one (value)" that is farther from the verb.

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/1/